# Dynamic active class with variables php

Tags: php, html

I want to add `class= "active"` to my link using php but the challenge am having is that my links have variables attached to them `.php?foobar=somevariable`. so, some how the class active is being ignored. Here is my snippet

```
<?php
//we need to set a var to find what page we are on
$pageOn2 = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

?>
```

And below is my html

```
<li class="<?php if($pageOn2 == 'regionalsummits.php?summit=eastern'){?> current-menu-item <?php }?>">
                                <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=eastern">Eastern Region</a>
                            </li>
                             <li class="<?php if($pageOn2 == 'regionalsummits.php?summit=southern'){?> current-menu-item<?php }?>">
                                <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=southern">South Western Region</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="<?php if($pageOn2 == 'regionalsummits.php?summit=western'){?> current-menu-item<?php }?>">
                                <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=western">Western Region</a>
                            </li>
```

Any help on where am goinh wrong

Comment: Is your matching working fine?

Comment: You try to match with this variables eastern,southern,western

Comment: yes its fine, cross checked everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try saving paramater in variable and then check**

```
<?php
$variable = $_GET['foobar'];
?>

<li class="<?php if($variable == 'eastern'){ echo 'current-menu-item'; } ?>"> <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=eastern">Eastern Region</a> </li>
<li class="<?php if($variable == 'southern'){ echo 'current-menu-item'; }?>"> <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=southern">South Western Region</a> </li>
<li class="<?php if($variable == 'western'){ echo 'current-menu-item'; } ?>"> <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=western">Western Region</a> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$pageOn2 = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` in this line of code the variable `$pageOn2` will recieve the value regionalsummits.php it will not get the query string cuz `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` this will not return the query string

so you can do this like:

```
$pageOn2 = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way ,you can do it some other way .
I have added a snippet for the better understanding.

```html
<?php
$pageOn2 = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
?>
<li class="<?php if ($pageOn2 == 'summit=eastern') { ?> current-menu-item <?php } ?>">
    <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=eastern">Eastern Region</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php if ($pageOn2 == 'summit=southern') { ?> current-menu-item<?php } ?>">
    <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=southern">South Western Region</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php if ($pageOn2 == 'summit=western') { ?> current-menu-item<?php } ?>">
    <a href="regionalsummits.php?summit=western">Western Region</a>
</li>

<style>
    .current-menu-item
    {
        background-color:red;  
    }
</style>
```